# C# WPF: Using Generic Views: Not Possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics

I am new to WPF, have read some books about it, but now I am stuck.

I have a generic class and a few concrete implementation of it

```
public class Question<T>
{
    List<T> AvailableAnswers;
    T Correct Answer;
    MidiSound SoundFragment;
    String Question;
}

public class IntervalQuestion : Question<Interval>
public class ScaleQuestion : Question<Scale>
```

I want my view to display the question, let the user choose between the answers etc.

I only can't find a way to implement this with WPF, it looks like you can't create a view that is based on a generic object?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It is possible by now using `XAML 2009's x:TargetType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributions of WPF and XAML don't come with built in support for generic types, but it's possible to extend WPF using markup extensions to provide some support.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml), and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehillberg/archive/2006/10/06/LimitedGenericsSupportInXaml.aspx)