# How to add Type Parameters to XAML

Tags: wpf, generics, xaml

I have the following class:

```
public class DefaultDropTargetAdvisor : IDropTargetAdvisor 
{
```

I decided to make it have a generic parameter:

```
public class DefaultDropTargetAdvisor<TDragType>
       : IDropTargetAdvisor where TDragType : class
{
```

This was my XAML before the change:

```
<local:DefaultDropTargetAdvisor x:Key="targetAdvisor1"/>
```

How do I change that XAML to now reflect the type parameter?  (I want to pass in a class called MockWI).

Clearly this does not work:

```
<local:DefaultDropTargetAdvisor<local:MockWI> x:Key="targetAdvisor1"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I specify a generic type in XAML (pre .NET 4 Framework)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml-pre-net-4-framework)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out an identical SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml).