# How to Achieve Lazy Binding of Tab Page Controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, lazy-loading, tabcontrol

I have an entity class. This entity has lots of properties and entity's data is shown to the user in several `TabItems` of a `TabControl`. I also implement MVVM approach.

When the screen is shown to the user first,  I want to bind only the active tab page controls and as the user navigates through tab pages additional separate bindings will be incurred as-needed. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy loading WPF tab content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274629/lazy-loading-wpf-tab-content)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have anything to do, that's the default behavior. The `DataTemplate` for a `TabItem` content won't be instantiated until this `TabItem` is selected

---

EDIT: here's an example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Page1ViewModel}">
        <v:Page1View />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Page3ViewModel}">
        <v:Page3View />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Page3ViewModel}">
        <v:Page3View />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

...

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Title">
</TabControl>
```

In the code above, the `TabControl` will pick the appropriate `DataTemplate` based on the item type, and will render it only when that item is selected.

---

EDIT 2: apparently you want to display the data of a single ViewModel on several pages. If you want the controls of each `TabItem` to lazily instantiated, you need to use the `ContentTemplate` property of each `TabItem`:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Page 1">
        <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <v:Page1View />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Page 2">
        <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <v:Page2View />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Page 3">
        <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <v:Page3View />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: @Thomas : Thanks so much four your response. Can you give me some useful links about this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any link about it... It doesn't seem to be documented

Comment: @Thomas : If I don't use DataTemplates for a tab item, is the same default lazy binding behaviour is effective?

Comment: No, it works only with templates. See my updated answer for an example

Comment: @Thomas : Thanks for your detailed response. But I have only one viewmodel.How can I achieve lazy binding of the tab items? Thanks so much.

Comment: Oh, I see... you display the data of a single ViewModel on several pages, right ? In that case, rather than defining direct content in each TabItem, write a ContentTemplate for each TabItem. Sample code coming soon...

Comment: @Thomas: I implemented as you said. But getters of all viewmodel properties are executed, although I don' t navigate through tab pages. This means that all bindings occurred and lazy binding is not occurred.

Comment: Not necessarily... If you put breakpoints in the constructors of your UserControls, you will see they are not instantiated until the tab is selected. Anyway, I don't think it deserves a downvote...

Comment: @Thomas : My other question was about ContentTemplate usage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510114/databinding-problem-in-contenttemplate-of-a-tabcontrol. I implemented your solution as a sample project. But I was not successful. Unfortunately, all getters are executed.

Comment: So the  tabcontrol itemsource (Pages) is just a collection of ViewModels?

Comment: One up vote is no enough. By using this technique the time WPF took to open some of our more complex forms went from 1+ second to almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

I created this solution which works for our third party tabcontrol.

The idea is to "intercept" the datacontext when it is beeing set, save it for later and set the datacontext back to null. When the tabitem gets focus we then set the datacontext and the data will populate in the tab.

Implemented as a dependency property. Then simply set the property on the tabs that need to (do not set it on the tab that comes up as a default)

```
    #region SavedDataContext

    private static object GetSavedDataContext(TabItemEx tabItem)
    {
        return tabItem.GetValue(SavedDataContextProperty);
    }

    private static void SetSavedDataContext(TabItemEx tabItem, object value)
    {
        tabItem.SetValue(SavedDataContextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SavedDataContextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SavedDataContext", typeof(object),
                                            typeof(Attach), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    #region LazyLoad

    public static bool GetLazyLoad(TabItemEx tabItem)
    {
        return (bool)tabItem.GetValue(LazyLoadProperty);
    }

    public static void SetLazyLoad(TabItemEx tabItem, bool value)
    {
        tabItem.SetValue(LazyLoadProperty, value);
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty LazyLoadProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LazyLoad", typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(Attach), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, LazyLoadPropertyChanged));

    private static void LazyLoadPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if ((bool)eventArgs.NewValue)
        {
            var tabItemEx = sender as TabItemEx;
            if (tabItemEx == null)
                return;

            tabItemEx.DataContextChanged += DataContextChanged;
            tabItemEx.GotFocus += TabGotFocus;
        }
    }


    #endregion

    private static void TabGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabItemEx = sender as TabItemEx;

        if (tabItemEx == null)
            return;

        tabItemEx.GotFocus -= TabGotFocus;
        tabItemEx.DataContext = GetSavedDataContext(tabItemEx);
        tabItemEx.IsSelected = true;
    }

    private static void DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var tabItemEx = sender as TabItemEx;

        if (tabItemEx == null)
            return;

        SetSavedDataContext(tabItemEx, eventArgs.NewValue);

        tabItemEx.DataContextChanged -= DataContextChanged;
        tabItemEx.DataContext = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Marked as answer approach has one drawback - content of TabItem will be always re-rendered when selected. If it's critical - you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12498528/1636137).