# lazy loading in TabControls (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have an TabControl which displays a collection of my ViewModels. The mapping between ViewModel and View is implemented by DataTemplate. I use MVVM but without PRISM (for historical reasons). The ViewModel’s Base class has a method `Load` which load information. What I want to do is to call this method only when a TabItem corresponding to the current ViewModel  is chosen (lazy loading).  Any ideas?
PS I found answers to a similar question - [Lazy loading WPF tab content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274629/lazy-loading-wpf-tab-content-)  but I can’t understand how to use approach 2 in MVVM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TabItem as any Selector item has the IsSelected property. You may try to bind it with view model using two-way binding. When model's IsSelected set to true for the first time, you may load your data.

XAML:

```
<TabControl ...>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Sample model:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isLoaded;

    private void Load()
    {
        // code
    }

    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return this._isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._isSelected != value)
            {
                this._isSelected = value;

                if (this._isSelected && !this._isLoaded)
                {
                    this.Load();
                    this._isLoaded = true;
                }

                var propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (propertyChanged != null)
                {
                    propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: 1. I can't understand how to use the IsSelected property - I have only TabControl and UserControls which are displayed in it. So I don't have explicit TabItems and don't know how to get them.

Comment: 2. If I even got TabItem, I can't understand ho IsSelected property can help me. Where can I check if IsSelectedIsTrueForThe1stTime then call my Load method?

Comment: I've added example to my answer

Answer (score 5):

Another way. This is basically simulating a `SelectedTabChanged` event in MVVM.

It works by binding the `Name` property of the tab to a `SelectedTabName` property in the viewmodel to which you can do whatever you want (including preventing tab changes by setting the value back to its previous value).

**ViewModel**

```
    public string _selectedTabName;
    public string SelectedTabName
    {
        get { return _selectedTabName; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTabName != value)
            {
                _selectedTabName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTabName");

                if (SelectedTabName == "EVENTS" && EventsLoaded == false)
                {
                    LoadEvents();
                }

                if (SelectedTabName == "MESSAGES" && MessagesLoaded == false)
                {
                    LoadMessages();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
 <TabControl SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTabName}">
     <TabItem Header="Events" Name="EVENTS">
         ...
     </TabItem>
     <TabItem Header="Messages" Name="MESSAGES">
         ...
     </TabItem>
  </TabControl>
```