# Prism: Lazy-load views into a tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, tabcontrol

I'm using Prism 4.1 to write a composite application that uses a `TabControl` as a means of switching between the main modes of the application.  I'm currently able to load views into the `TabControl` as separate tabs by simply navigating to the view with the `TabControl` region as the target:

In my `Shell.xaml`:

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TabRegion" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in my `Bootstrapper.cs`, in the `InitializeShell()` method:

```
regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"].RequestNavigate("FirstTabView");
regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"].RequestNavigate("SecondTabView");
regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"].RequestNavigate("ThirdTabView");
```

However, the views and (more importantly) their respective ViewModels are instantiated immediately when the application starts, rather than when a view's tab is selected.  Is there a way to configure Prism to only load a view when its tab has been activated?

I've tried defining the views in separate modules, and loading the modules with the `InitializationMode.OnDemand` parameter, but this doesn't seem to have any effect; I'm assuming this is because the `RequestNavigate` method is enough to activate the module.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like this was discussed previously [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756657/lazy-loading-in-tabcontrols-mvvm)