# WPF Page Within Tabcontrol TabItem Lazy loading

Tags: c#, wpf, lazy-loading, tabcontrol

I have Xaml WPF window with `TabControl` inside. Each `TabItem` of it contains a page inside frame like this:

```
 <TabItem >
            <TabItem.Header>
                Users
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Frame Source="/Views/UsersPage.xaml"  />
 </TabItem>
 <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                Stats
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Frame Source="/Views/OrdersPage.xaml"/>
</TabItem>
```

The problem is when i open this window all pages inside frames loads simultaneously, so if , eg, I put `MessageBox` on each page load i got a lot of them. I want my pages to load only when I click on  corresponding tab header.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Put your `Frame.Source` or `MessageBox` assignment into a custom init function and call it upon `SelctionChanged` of the `TabControl` in the corresponding `TabItem` that got selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756657/lazy-loading-in-tabcontrols-mvvm . You are looking for lazy loading, which would load the current tab on demand vs all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to inherit from `TabItem` like this:

```
public class MyCustomTabItem : TabItem
{
    public void MyCustomInitFunction()
    {
        //Do all your stuff here
    }
}
```

In there put all your stuff that is supposed to be happening when the control gets clicked.

Create your `TabControl` with those new items:

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="myTabControl_SelectionChanged" Name="myTabControl">
    <MyCustomTabItem Name="myTab1">
        <MyCustomTabItem.Header>
            Users
        </MyCustomTabItem.Header>
        <Frame Source="/Views/UsersPage.xaml"  />
     </MyCustomTabItem>
     <MyCustomTabItem Name="myTab2">
        <MyCustomTabItem.Header>
            Stats
        </MyCustomTabItem.Header>
        <Frame Source="/Views/OrdersPage.xaml"/>
    </MyCustomTabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Hookup the `SelectionChanged` event handler to call your special init function:

```
private void myTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tc = (TabControl)e.Source;
    if(tc != null)
    {
        MyCustomTabItem ti = (MyCustomTabItem)tc.Items[tc.SelectedIndex];
        if(ti != null)
        {
            ti.MyCustomInitFunction()
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want this to happen the first time it get's shown put a `bool` variable in your `MyCustomTabItem` class that keeps track if it has already happened once, and if so just return instead of running it again.