# How to reference a generic type in the DataType attribute of a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a ViewModel defined like this:

```
public class LocationTreeViewModel<TTree> : 
    ObservableCollection<TTree>, INotifyPropertyChanged
        TTree : TreeBase<TTree>
```

I want to reference it in the `DataType` attribute of a `DataTemplate` in XAML. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I specify a generic type in XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml)

Comment: Try x:TypeArgument

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you cannot express a generics type in XAML. You will have to create a concrete type that extends your generic one ...

```
public class FooLocationTreeViewModel : LocationTreeViewModel<Foo>
{
}
```

Comment: I used this technique with success but ultimately [built a generic wrapper, see my answer expounding on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33827448/11635)

Comment: IMO you should update your answer. Because you **can** express a closed generic type in xaml (more or less). See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124755/1353211

Answer (score 5):

I know, that I'm a little late to the party, but I want post an answer for all those who may see this question in the future:

It is possible.

You can see the whole code in the answer to this question: [DataTemplates and Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092789/datatemplates-and-generics). But since it is quite long, I will just copy the important bits. If you want more details, then look into the referenced question.

1. You need to write a `MarkupExtension` which can provide a closed generic type.

   ```
   public class GenericType : MarkupExtension
   {
       public GenericType() { }

       public GenericType(Type baseType, params Type[] innerTypes)
       {
           BaseType = baseType;
           InnerTypes = innerTypes;
       }

       public Type BaseType { get; set; }

       public Type[] InnerTypes { get; set; }

       public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       {
           Type result = BaseType.MakeGenericType(InnerTypes);
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now you can define your type which closes your generic type in xaml, and then use the closed generic type as `DataType` of an `DataTemplate`.

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <x:Array Type="{x:Type System:Type}" 
                x:Key="ListWithTwoStringTypes">
           <x:Type TypeName="System:String" />
           <x:Type TypeName="System:String" />
       </x:Array>

       <WpfApp1:GenericType BaseType="{x:Type TypeName=Generic:Dictionary`2}" 
                          InnerTypes="{StaticResource ListWithTwoStringTypes}"
                          x:Key="DictionaryStringString" />

       <DataTemplate DataType="{StaticResource DictionaryStringString}">
           <TextBlock Text="Hi Dictionary"
                  FontSize="40"
                  Foreground="Cyan"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
   ```
3. Be happy that the defined `DataTemplate` gets automatically selected by WPF.

Answer (score 3):

In XAML 2006 this is not supported. You can, however, roll your own if you want to have this functionality.

[This link](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/03/09/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf-and-soon-silverlight) has a nice tutorial on creating markup extensions.

Usage would be like this:

```
<Grid xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:CustomMarkupExtensions">
  <TextBlock Text="{ext:GenericType FooLocationTreeViewModel(Of Foo)}" />
</Grid>
```

You have to choose and implement the syntax though. I suggest the VB notation since it won't interfere like the C# notation does with < and >.

Comment: wont work as the `DataType` bit of a `DataTemplate` doesnt permit markup extensions

Answer (score 2):

Late and not exactly the answer to the question (CollinE and Bas already sayed the it is actually not possible)... However, maybe the alternativ solution may be helpful for others:

It is possible to resolve generic types by using a TemplateSelector like that:

**TemplateSelector**

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var genericType = typeof(MyGenericType<>);
        var isMyGeneric = item?.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType;

        return isMyGeneric ? MyTemplate : OtherTemplate;
    }

    public DataTemplate MyTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OtherTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">            
                <!-- Set Up MyTemplate -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="OtherTemplate">
            <!-- Set Up OtherTemplate -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"
                                MyTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
                                OtherTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" 
                Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.DataType>
        <x:Type Type="ns:MyGenericClass`1"/>
    </DataTemplate.DataType>
</DataTemplate>
```

Replace `1 for the amount of generic parameters you have, e.g.:

```
public class MyGenericClass<TParent, TChild>
```

would be declared:

```
<x:Type Type="ns:MyGenericClass`2"/>
```

Comment: I get Character '\`' was unexpected in string 'ns:MyGenericClass\`1'.  Invalid XAML type name.

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a workaround that is certainly less than perfect, and does require a bit of code in your ViewModel (which. because the VM shouldn't know about the view, breaks strict MVVM).

Define your generic type, and then define a class of that type with the lowest-common-ancestor as the type argument:

```cs
class GenericClass<T> { }

class Class1 : GenericClass<Apples> { }

class Class2 : GenericClass<Oranges> { }

class WorkaroundClass : GenericClass<Fruit> { }
```

In your viewmodel you'll need to declare your bound member as the ancestor type, and cast it.

```cs
// instead of:
// Apple DisplayFruit => GetGrannySmith();

Fruit DisplayFruit => (Fruit)GetGrannySmith();
```

In your xaml, you can then bind your data template to the ancestor class:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WorkaroundClass}"/>
```

I'm pretty sure that because the Generic parent is, well, generic, you shouldn't run into any actual cases where the differences between your type arguments cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Suprisingly, this works properly:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="GenericClass&lt;TypeArgument1,TypeArgument2&gt;">
```

Just copy the C# type and replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;` (those are XML escape sequences)

Answer (score 0):

Define your generic types in the static class.

```
public static GenericTypes {
  public static Type TreeViewOfITreeItem => typeof(TreeView<ITreeItem>);
}
```

And then use it in the DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Static mhui:GenericTypes.TreeViewOfITreeItem}">
```

Answer (score -1):

The {x:Type} markup extension supports allows generic type arguments to be specified as a comma separated list in parentheses.

Here's an example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:generic="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type generic:List(sys:Int64)}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

I am using .Net 4.5 on VS 2015, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: This does not compile, at least not with framework 4.7.2 in VS2017. And I only found mention of a comma separated list in parentheses in the `x:TypeArguments` documentation, but not for `x:Type`.

Answer (score -2):

The only way i could do this is to use `MarkupExtensions`.

```
public class GenericType : MarkupExtension
{
     private readonly Type _of;
     public GenericType(Type of)
     {
         _of = of;
     }
     public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
     {
         return typeof(LocationTreeViewModel<>).MakeGenericType(_of);
     }
}
```

And to use it i just need to do this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{app:GenericType app:TreeBaseClass}">
```

Comment: @franssu:Thanks for your comment,but i don't understand what you mean?i didnt want to use this for every generic classes,i don't think its even possible!
Do you have a better solution?

Comment: -1: Unfortunately this triggers a MC error; `DataTemplate`'s `DataType` can only accept a predefined set of extensions [such as `x:Type`]. Suck up [@ColinE's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10005490/11635) was my conclusion

Comment: This answer deserves an upvote because it's theoretically possible.  And -4 votes is unfair.  It's hard to answer these questions - keep em coming please.

Answer (score -2):

Slightly improved version of MarkupExtension, work for classes upto 3 generic parameters.

```
  public class GenericTypeExtension : MarkupExtension
  {
    public GenericTypeExtension()
    {

    }
    public GenericTypeExtension(string baseTypeName_, Type genericType1_, Type genericType2_, Type genericType3_)
    {
      BaseTypeName = baseTypeName_;
      GenericType1 = genericType1_;
      GenericType2 = genericType2_;
      GenericType3 = genericType3_;
    }
    public string BaseTypeName { get; set; }
    public string BaseTypeAssemblyName { get; set; }
    public Type GenericType1 { get; set; }
    public Type GenericType2 { get; set; }
    public Type GenericType3 { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider_)
    {
      var list = new List<Type>();
      if (GenericType1 != null)
      {
        list.Add(GenericType1);
      }
      if (GenericType2 != null)
      {
        list.Add(GenericType2);
      }
      if (GenericType3 != null)
      {
        list.Add(GenericType3);
      }

      var type = Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}`{1}, {2}", BaseTypeName, list.Count, BaseTypeAssemblyName));
      if (type != null)
      {
        return type.MakeGenericType(list.ToArray());
      }
      return null;
    }

  }
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP - no use for datatemplates

Comment: Actually, this kind of does.  You then use the markup extension in the DataType field of the DataTemplate.