# Why does WPF fire a Loaded event for a view as soon as it is added to a TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple C# WPF application looking like this:

[image]

I'm adding Item2 programmatically, and I wonder why the `Loaded` event is fired both shortly after it has been added to the `TabControl` and then again when I open it.

The code for my `MainWindow.xaml` looks as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="MyTabControl" >
            <TabItem Name="Item1" Header="Item1">
                <local:Control1 />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And its code-behind is:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
        {
            var item = new TabItem
            {
                Content = new Control2(),
                Header = "Item2"
            };
            MyTabControl.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have one control called `Control1` and another called `Control2`. They are defined with the following `MyControl.xaml` file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the following code-behind `MyControl.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public abstract partial class MyControl
    {
        protected abstract string MyName { get; }

        protected MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += (sender, args) => Debug.Print("Loaded {0}", MyName);
            Unloaded += (sender, args) => Debug.Print("Unloaded {0}", MyName);
        }
    }

    public class Control1 : MyControl
    {
        protected override string MyName => "Control1";
    }

    public class Control2 : MyControl
    {
        protected override string MyName => "Control2";
    }
}
```

When I open the application, I get the following console output:

```
Loaded Control1
Loaded Control2
```

And when I switch to Item2:

```
Unloaded Control1
Loaded Control2
```

And back to Item1:

```
Unloaded Control2
Loaded Control1
```

The latter two make sense; when I navigate from a control it gets unloaded while the new control gets loaded.

However, I don't understand why Control2 is loaded initially, before it has been shown. This causes Control2 to receive two `Loaded` events in a row, before it gets an `Unloaded` event.

Answer (score 0):

When we add Tab Items explicitly, each tab item is loaded and initialized immediately containing everything.(Please refer to this topic for more details [Lazy loading WPF tab content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274629/lazy-loading-wpf-tab-content))