# Wpf inherited usercontrol can not use resources property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, user-controls

i have build my own usercontrol template, the inherited class looks like:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using CustomCopyNas.Views;

namespace CustomCopyNas.MVVM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for all Views that is used in MVVM
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TViewModel">ViewModel</typeparam>
    public class ViewBase<TViewModel> : UserControl, IView<TViewModel> where TViewModel : UploadViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewBase()
        { }

        public ViewBase(TViewModel tViewModel)
        {
            ViewModel = tViewModel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ViewModel
        /// </summary>
        public TViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return (TViewModel)DataContext;
            }
            private set
            {
                DataContext = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my xaml file

```
<mvvm:ViewBase x:Class="CustomCopyNas.Controls.FolderControl"
             x:TypeArguments="vm:FolderViewModel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:CustomCopyNas.MVVM"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CustomCopyNas.Views"
             xmlns:enum="clr-namespace:CustomCopyNas.Enum"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Width="700">

    <mvvm:ViewBase.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="osEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type Type="enum:OsType"></x:Type>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </mvvm:ViewBase.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Folders, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Folder or File" Binding="{Binding Path}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>    
    </Grid>
</mvvm:ViewBase>
```

and partial class

```
using CustomCopyNas.MVVM;
using CustomCopyNas.Views;

namespace CustomCopyNas.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for FolderControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class FolderControl : ViewBase<FolderViewModel>
    {

        public FolderControl()
            : base(new FolderViewModel("SourceFolders.xml"))
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

When i am trying to compile, i've got error, that the property resources does not exist on viewbase. I counld not figure out, where the error is and my viewbase class is inherited from usercontrol class, this provide resources property.
What is here wrong?

Comment: Where is your partial class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problems are caused because generic classes are not supported in XAML. You can read the full story in the [Generics in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee956431%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page on MSDN, but in short, from the linked page:

> In XAML, a generic type must always be represented as a constrained generic; an unconstrained generic is never present in the XAML type system or a XAML node stream and cannot be represented in XAML markup.

As such, you have a mismatch between your code class declaration:

```
public class ViewBase<TViewModel>
```

And your XAML class declaration:

```
<mvvm:ViewBase x:Class="CustomCopyNas.Controls.FolderControl"
```

The fact that they do not match will cause you a variety of problems.

Please see the [Can I specify a generic type in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml) and [WPF UserControl with generic code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811179/wpf-usercontrol-with-generic-code-behind) questions for further information on this subject.