# How to create a generic xaml user control in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, user-controls

I'm getting a weird XAML error that I don't understand that I'm hoping someone can help with.  I am attempting to make a generic `AxisBase` user control that is capable of plotting any type of data.  I then want to extend this to create a specific kind of axis, one that can graph dates on the X axis and doubles on the Y axis.

**DateDoubleAxis.xaml**

```
<axis:AxisBase  x:Class="project.Views.Controls.Chart.Axis.DateDoubleAxis"
                x:TypeArguments="system:DateTime, system:Double"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:axis="using:project.Views.Controls.Chart.Axis"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:system="using:System">...</axis:AxisBase>
```

**AxisBase.cs**

```
namespace project.Views.Controls.Chart.Axis
{
    public class AxisBase<TX, TY> : UserControl {...}
}
```

**DateDoubleAxis.xaml.cs**

```
namespace project.Views.Controls.Chart.Axis 
{
    public sealed partial class DateDoubleAxis : AxisBase<DateTime, Double> {...}
}
```

But I'm getting a couple weird errors.  In the xaml declaration of `DateDoubleAxis` I get the error

> The name "AxisBase`2" does not exist in the namespace "using:project.Views.Controls.Chart.Axis"

The '`2' I believe comes from the fact that `AxisBase` has two generic types associated with it.

And then in the declaration of `DateDoubleAxis` I get the error:

> Base class of 'project.Views.Controls.Chart.Axis.DateDoubleAxis' differs from declared in other parts

Along with the ironic resharper warning

> Base type 'AxisBase' is already specified in other parts

I realize I'm doing something a little weird in trying to extend from my own user control, but I think that it makes sense in this context, and at the very least, a few users have suggested it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811179/wpf-usercontrol-with-generic-code-behind).

Can anyone point me to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Your `AxisBase` cannot take generic type since it has the xaml part. You should keep it as a normal usercontrol, and have `DateDoubleAxis` be `DateDoubleAxis<TX, TY>` and inherits from `AxisBase`.

Comment: @JustinXL `AxisBase` does not have a xaml component (I added file names to make this more clear).  I am intending for the `DateDoubleAxis.xaml` snippet to show that `DateDoubleAxis` is an `AxisBase<DateTime, Double>` to mimic the class declaration in `DateDoubleAxis.xaml.cs`.  Is that not actually what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized that you are using

```
x:TypeArguments="system:DateTime, system:Double"
```

in your XAML. Unfortunately this is not supported in UWP. Also keep in mind that `Double` in XAML should be defined as `x:Double` instead of `system:Double`. But this is irrelevant in this case anyway.

The only way I got this working in my project is create a `UserControl` (with XAML file) as the *base* of anything, and then create a *generic class* that inherits from it. Once the generic class is in place, I just create a bunch of *derived classes* based on it with different types. For example in your case, you would have

**Base `UserControl`: `AxisBase`**

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.AxisBase"

public partial class AxisBase : UserControl
{
    public AxisBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Generic class: `AxisOfT`**

```
public class AxisOfT<TX, TY> : AxisBase { }
```

**Derived class: `DateDoubleAxis`**

```
public class DateDoubleAxis : AxisOfT<DateTime, double> { }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer on this @JustinXL.  Your answer compiles, which is great, but doesn't allow the derived class to have a XAML part, which is unfortunate.  This essentially means to me that a generic user control cannot exist.  I'm hesitant to check your answer because it seems a "correct" one does not exist, but I will do so out of appreciation for your time =)

Comment: Please vote [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/610869/support-generic-type-arguments-in-uwp-xaml.html).