# Can Generics be used with Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, generics

I have a user control that displays objects of a client-declared type with some specialized behavior. I would like to use generics. However, I'm not sure how to declare this in the XAML:

```
<local:EditableListBox x:Name="SectionList" Margin="56,8,15,0" FontSize="64" SelectionChanged="SectionList_SelectionChanged" />
```

`ListBox` uses `object` members, which makes me think that perhaps there's no way to have type safety here. Or is there?

(I'm building a Windows Phone 7 app, if it makes any difference.)

**Update**: I'm totally fine with not having generics in the XAML, but I'm still trying to figure out how to set it up in the code-behind. I parameterized everything, but it's still complaining.

Code behind:

```
public partial class EditableListBox<T> : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged where T : IEditableListMember {

    public EditableListBox()
    {
        // Error: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(EditableListBox_Loaded);
    }

    // ...

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            // Error: The name 'ContentListBox' does not exist in the current context   
            return ContentListBox.SelectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            // Error: The name 'ContentListBox' does not exist in the current context   
            ContentListBox.SelectedIndex = value;
        }
    }
```

The XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListBox x:Name="ContentListBox">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid ManipulationCompleted="Grid_ManipulationCompleted">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           Width="96"
                           Height="96"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Visibility="{Binding Editing, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}"
                           />

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               Foreground="{Binding Enabled, Converter={StaticResource enabledConverter}}" />

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

It gives two compiler errors: the `ListBox` `ContentListBox` and `InitializeComponent()` are not defined. I suspect that the problem has something to do with how the class is split into two `partial` definitions, and mine is parameterized whereas the generated code is not. How can I get around this?

Comment: Apparently not out of the box. Have a look at can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml

Comment: Anything that needs to be declared in XAML can not have a generic parameter.  I would recommend not trying generics on anything that derives from `Control` but it is possible to create it in code.  There is no way to specify the generics in the XAML so your code behind can not have a generic parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't use generic types in Silverlight XAML directly.

But you could familiarize yourself with the [MVVM pattern](http://www.bing.com/search?q=silverlight+mvvm&go=&form=QBLH&filt=all). Your models and viewmodels can easily be generic types, and you can do all your coding there. The XAML views are dumb, have no or few code behind, and only bind to the view models.

Answer (score 0):

you CAN use generics in the code-behind. not so much in the XAML. sorry.  You are pretty much going to have to generate the XAML or create the controls (etc.) in your codebehind, I am thinking.

[**Clarification**]
What I mean is, in the code-behind you can use generics as you would expect. making a `List<>` of T, Making a `Dicationary<>`, etc.

You can generate XAML on the fly using XamlReader and XamlWriter.

Comment: Can you specify how? I'm trying to do so but it's not working (see above).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Silverlight. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml) post gives a link to a alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use generics in XAML, but they can be used in the C# code of your Silverlight project. If you're able to, you can create a derived type from the generic type with a type specified and then create that in XAML.