# Generics in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, generics, xaml

is it possible to write something like this in XAML:

`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EntityListViewModel<T>}">`

**BUT**

I need to specify generics because the declaration is `EntityListViewModel<T>`.

Comment: XAML doesn't support binding to generic types yet, even if the generic parameters are concrete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I specify a generic type in XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml)

Comment: Somehow I don't think we need another level of complexity in XAML

Comment: I guess, it wouldn't be that hard to implement it and sometimes it might be useful.

Comment: @BoltClock: Actually it does in .Net 4.0. See http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/01/xaml-using-generic-types-in-xaml-2009.aspx. But not in 'compiled' xaml

Comment: @Lars: Oh that sounds fancy, thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be use DataTemplateSelector.

Answer (score 0):

There are some support for generics in xaml 2009
http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/06/01/xaml-using-generic-types-in-xaml-2009.aspx

But im not sure if that works with datatemplate.

You could however experiment with setting the DataType property **from code**... i havet tried that though :)