# DataTemplates and generic types

Tags: c#, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a generic class

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T>
```

Since I am trying to create a DataTemplate that will be applied to all classes that derive from BaseViewModel, I set the type to BaseViewModel:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BaseViewModel}">
```

However, this does not work since it looks like xaml does not support generic data types.

Are there any work arounds to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I specify a generic type in XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would create a non-generic version of `BaseViewModel` and let the generic one inherit from it:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    // members that are not T-specific, if any
    // (not required, but could prove useful)
}

public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : BaseViewModel
{
    // T-specific members
}
```

By doing this, your `DataTemplate` is going to work.