# Generic classes don't bind to HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm new to WPF so may be missing something obvious but haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.

Basically I'm building a custom tree collection that sorts in a particular way and the nodes of the tree are typed to the type of the collection. When testing in a `TreeView` the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` doesn't work when the nodes are generic. If they're not generic it's fine.

Here's a simple node class to illustrate:

```
public class SimpleNode<T>
{
    private List<SimpleNode<T>> _children;
    private string _name;

    public SimpleNode(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public List<SimpleNode<T>> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }
        set
        {
            _children = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }
}
```

then in the xaml:

```
HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SimpleNode`1}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
```

Apparently the `1 appended to the type is a result of `SimpleNode` having 1 generic param. If I strip the class of generics the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` works and I can view the tree in the `TreeView`. With the generics in place it won't do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for that out of the box. But you can make it work by creating your own `DataTemplateSelector` that supports generics:

```
public class OpenGenericTypeDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,
                                                DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (item != null && element != null)
        {
            if (item.GetType().IsGenericType)
            {
                var genericTypeDefinition = item.GetType()
                                                .GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                var key = new DataTemplateKey(genericTypeDefinition);
                return element.TryFindResource(key) as DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You than can use it like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <OpenGenericTypeDataTemplateSelector x:Key="GenericTemplateSelector" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<TreeView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource GenericTemplateSelector}" ...>
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SimpleNode`1}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      ...
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
```

What that does is actually very simple:
When you create a `DataTemplate` for a certain type, that type's name will automatically become the key of that template.
The default `DataTemplateSelector` uses the type of the item as lookup value. But the type of a an instance of a generic class is a *closed generic type*, i.e. one that has the generic type parameter specified.
Problem is: The template has been registered for the *open generic type*, i.e. without the generic type parameter specified. That's why the default `DataTemplateSelector` doesn't pick up `DataTemplate`s registered for an open generic type.
The implementation I provided adds support for open generic types by simply checking the type of the item. If it is generic, we get ourselves the open generic type (via `GetGenericTypeDefinition`) and use that as the key.

To actually make use of this selector, we have to tell the `TreeView` that it should use it. We are doing that by specifying the `ItemTemplateSelector`.

Comment: great thanks, I'll take a look through and see if I can figure out what you've done here. Also for a quick solution I found another post which suggests making a non generic base class and refering to it in the WPF - this seems to work too. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586528/datatemplates-and-generic-types

Comment: @user1373164: I added an explanation what happens here. A non-generic base class works, sure, but it is only a workaround for a short-coming of the implementation of the standard `DataTemplateSelector` and thus I wouldn't recommand it.