# WPF - How to access type of public field in code-behind of a Window

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I try to combine my already defined collection `TheCollection` with xaml-defined collection `GreekHeroesData`

ToCollectionWindow.xaml.vb:

```
Public Class ToCollectionWindow
    Public myCollection As New ObservableCollection(Of Person)

    Public ReadOnly Property TheCollection As ObservableCollection(Of Person)
        Get
            Return myCollection
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub InitYo(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        myCollection.Add(New Person("one"))
        myCollection.Add(New Person("two"))
        myCollection.Add(New Person("three"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

ToCollectionWindow.xaml

```
<Window ...
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="GreekHeroesData" XPath="GreekHeroes/Hero">
    <x:XData>
        <GreekHeroes xmlns="">
            <Hero Name="Jason" />
            <Hero Name="Hercules" />
            <Hero Name="Bellerophon" />
            <Hero Name="Theseus" />
            <Hero Name="Odysseus" />
            <Hero Name="Perseus" />
        </GreekHeroes>
    </x:XData>
</XmlDataProvider>
...
```

Here's what I try:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TheCollection}">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Gold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="Hero">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Cyan" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox Width="200" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding TheCollection}" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GreekHeroesData}}" />
            <ListBoxItem Foreground="Red">Other Listbox Item 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Foreground="Red">Other Listbox Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

It failed on build:
`The type reference cannot find a public type named 'TheCollection'.`

Comment: Have you set the DataContext?

Comment: @DavidSdot Sorry, I forgot to include it here: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` is set on Window element.
See the updated post.

Comment: You have to provide namespace for the type `TheCollection` and of course it should be a type(TheCollectionTYPE), not a propery in object.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite catch that.. `TheCollection` is a property which return the field `myCollection` with type `ObservableCollection(Of Person)`. How or why should that property have namespace? Do you mean XML namespace?

Comment: Yes! The problem is that you use generic collection. So you can't specify generic type for collection. See work around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586528/datatemplates-and-generic-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TheCollection` contains `Person` objects. So the `DataType` of the `DataTemplate` should be set to `Person`, i.e. it will be applied to all objects in `TheCollection`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Person}">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Gold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comment you have to specify XAML namespace for the type should be handled in DataTemplate. In your case it's an `ObservableCollection(Of Person)`. The real problem is, that you can't specify Generic Type for ObservableCollection in XAML.
So you have to do a work around(sorry for VB syntax, I do develop in C#):

```
namespace YourViewModelNameSpace
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    public class NonGenericPersonCollection : ObservableCollection<Person> { }
    //Public Class NonGenericPersonCollection Inherits ObservableCollection(Of Person)
}
Public ReadOnly Property TheCollection As NonGenericPersonCollection
```

```
<Window ...
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:YourViewModelNameSpace" />
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NonGenericPersonCollection}">
```