# Generic Type XAML 2009

Tags: wpf, generics, xaml, types, inheritance

I have a litte problems with these class

```
public class MyClass : MyGenericClass<String, Int32>
{

}

// XAML Class
public class MyGenericClass<T, U> : MyGenericClassBase<T, U>
    where U : class
    where T : class
{
    public MyGenericClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MyGenericClassBase<T, U>
    where U : class, new()
    where T : class, new()
{
    T _t;
    U _u;
    public MyGenericClassBase()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to did the class "MyGenericClass" in XAML but I can't !

I try it :

```
<MyGenericClassBase x:Class="MyGenericClass"  
         x:TypeArguments="class,class"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >

       ...
```

How can i pass the argument type at my "MyGenericClass" and the inherit class                 "MyGenericClassBase "

Thanks a lot

Nico

Comment: Please use the comment system under the answers you receive to write comments. Answers are reserved for just that, answers.

Answer (score 3):

**XAML 2006:**
You can't use generic types in xaml 2006. The easiest solution is to use MyClass directly.
Check out this question for other workarounds: [Can I specify a generic type in XAML (pre .NET 4 Framework)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185349/can-i-specify-a-generic-type-in-xaml)

**XAML 2009:**
Generic types are supported natively:

```
<MyGenericClass x:TypeArguments="x:Int32, x:String"> 
    ...
</MyGenericClass>
```

Comment: Hi Alfonso and thanks for your quick answer, But this topic didn't help me ! I can't use "MyClass" in XAML ! And my question is if I can use Generic Types in XAML Class ( not for the inherit class "MyGenericClassBase" but for my current class "MyGenericClass" ! Thanks

Comment: After doing some digging I found that generic types are supported natively in XAML 2009. I edited my answer to show you how to do this.

Comment: I know this case but it's working only for the inherited class and not for my primary class "MyGenericClass". The parameter x:TypeArguments of your code are only for the class "MyGenericClassBase" ! If you have another Idea ? thanks

Comment: Please could you tell what xmlns:x and where I should specify? Example gives exception "'x' is an undeclared prefix." after invoking XamlServices.Parse

Comment: OK, xmlns:x should be specified as xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"" on the MyGenericClass element itself or ancestor element. That's despite of x:String being from XAML 2009.